# Add a new Field to table and create .df file

Tags: progress-db

I want to create a new field in a existing table then want to create .df file for that?
So if anyone else will use that .df file, he/she should able to get that field.

Thanks,

Comment: What did you try? Have you seen any errors?

Comment: What you want is an incremental df-file. Check this answer - it  covers the same procedure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014933/creating-database-table-from-temp-table-by-code/24015622#24015622

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create an incremental df (definitions) file or a "delta.df".  You can easily do this from a command line:

```
bpro -db new -1 -db old -1 -p prodict/dump_inc.p
```

This will create a file called "delta.df".

The order of databases is important -- delta df will contain changes needed to make the second db like the first.  So to add a field that is in "new" to "old" do it as shown.  If you want a 2nd delta.df to back out the changes if your upgrade fails flip the order.

For more information: http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P103489